# What is the maximum current that the Max10 FPGA would require?

Tags: current, fpga, max10

I am currently working on a project where I use an FPGA Max10 from Intel.

Is there any approximate value of what the maximum current is, that the FPGA Max10 requires? I know that this highly depends on the application and a lot more factors. But is there any rough value?

Comment: The datasheet does not tell this. There are two ways to estimate this, one is an Excel sheet the other is Quartus. And how much it internally consumes is one thing, and how much external load such as LEDs it has is another thing.

Comment: That is true. I am searching for a rough current value for INTERNAL use. The external loads (LEDs,...) are calculated separately.

Comment: [www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01071-voltage-regulator-selection-fpgas.pdf](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/wp/wp-01071-voltage-regulator-selection-fpgas.pdf) refers to a power estimator for that family of chips.

Comment: Anecdotally:  MAX10 devices are very low power unless you are using a substantial amount of the internal logic at high speed with lots of transitions.  If the device is mostly idle, it will use almost nothing (it won't get warm).  In this family most designs are probably between 0 and 1W total power consumption.  If the design is doing continuous processing (AES or compression, for example), then it could be above this number, but probably no more than 5W given the limited resources in this family.

Answer (score 6):

Intel provide an Excel spreadsheet that allows you to put in various parameters (e.g. clock speed, resource usage, IO count, PLL usage, etc) which gives an estimate for the current requirements for each of the power rails.

You can download it from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/operation-and-testing/power/max-10-estimator-download.html). In case the link goes dead, the page title is "PowerPlay Early Power Estimator Download MAX 10 FPGAs Devices", which should help find it again in the future.

Comment: I am not working on a windows computer. Is there any other program that does not require excel?

Comment: @F_Schmidt, this is where you have to investigate for yourself or log a support call with Intel to ask. TC's described the manufacturer's support (upvoted) but can't be the personal support for you.

Comment: @F_Schmidt haven't tried that spreadsheet in particular, but I've never had *any* problem with libreoffice for this kind of tool. As Tony says, a high degree of "figuring out how to use a standard file format" is kind of expected there. "Not on windows" is also not very helpful, so next I propose a Linux tool, and you're also not on Linux.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Got your point. Next time I will write "work in Linux" and not "do not work on windows" ;)